# How to match text between quotation mark and a number

Tags: java, regex

I need to write a regex in Java, which would match the string `IPS` in the text `Mobilní telefon 6.26" IPS 2280x1080 FHD+`. It means a regex which would match a text between quotation mark and a number.

I wrote this `[^"] *[^\d]` but it is not working together.

Comment: You may probably use `(?<=").*?(?=[0-9])` or `"\s*(.*?)\s*[0-9]`

Comment: Don't forget to mention language/tool you're using.

Comment: it works, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following regex:

`"\s*(.*?)\s*\d`

The first capturing group contains the desired text.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/CB0G4b/2)